# How can I do this with CSS and HTML?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

It's hard to explain, but I'll try. I am trying to create a grid of divs that will never go off the page horizontally. Hence, the bottom scroll bar will never show. Instead, divs that are pushed off the window will wrap to the next row. There may not be as many divs on the bottom row as there are on the previous. In this case, the divs on the bottom row must be centered in the window.  As the window resizes, the margins between the divs should expand or shrink to equalize the space between them.  If the window resizes enough, the number of columns should change to fit the divs. Hopefully this image will help:
[image: Image of re-spacing grid-like layout]

float:left and display:inline-block are close, but they don't resize margins and are not centered. I would like this to be done with pure CSS and HTML, but I do know JavaScript if it is necessary.

Comment: [this is the use case for flexbox](http://codepen.io/zzzzBov/pen/KrkaXw).

Comment: Check this out: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: You can't maintain a consistent spacing. Each line is independent.

Comment: If you want the distance of the outer elements of all rows but the last one to the container borders to be of a fixed value, then I don't think this is possible with flexbox. It would require something along the lines of a separate setting for justify-content for the "last line," but I don't know of any way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using [flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)

### [Demo](http://codepen.io/kjantzer/pen/QEadOL)

The key parts are:

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around
}

.grid > div {
  flex-basis: 300px;
}
```

Comment: This does not "equalize the space" between all the flex items, as the question asked. It only does equalizes inside each flex line, but independently. I don't understand why it was accepted.

Comment: It's as close as you can get without JS

Comment: I accepted it because it was close enough.  Equalizing the space on the last line would probably take so much more work that it wouldn't be worth it. But I'll still take new ideas.